# Apply search filter on list returned by LiveData Android Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am loading a set of data from db using room and pagedList since it is a large set. I need to filter that data and show it to the user accordingly using the same pagedlistadapter. Please help.

dao is as follows

```
@WorkerThread
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :query ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAll(query: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, users>
```

Table has 4 fields -  id,name,phone,address

Comment: you need to share your dao method by which you are selecting the data from table, and need to share the detail of the OBJECT(Table)

Comment: @faiizii I have updated the question. first, I need to show all the users from the table and then while filtering, I need sho filtered users

Comment: ok your approach is perfect. we usually query data in this way, but you have problem in your sql query

Comment: @faiizii There is no problem with the query. % is added along with the string where the function is called.

Comment: remove this code and show how did you show the data at app ui ?

Comment: the search filter works fine with livedata. the problem is when using the pagedList(i have to implement pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Transformations.switchMap()` to requery the database any time the search term changes:

https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/cd7af7fbdd60933991ea7f8b966ca171bb594cb3/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/ui/list/ListViewModel.kt#L35

Or see Google's Paging Library codelab, which does the same thing:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :query ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAll(query: String): DataSource.Factory<Int, users>
```

Here's your **query** string must be like **%ABC%** where abc is the name of the user.

The **LIKE** key word is use to check/find the pattern in the records [Here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/) you can read the possible pattern searches

To attach the **% %** to your query string you need to call this function as

```
YOUR_HELPER.getAll("%".plus(YOUR_QUERY).plus("%"))
```

`plus()` uses for Concatenation.

Comment: % is added when calling the function and the query works fine. The problem I am facing is that I need to filter the livedata.

Comment: filter live data on what ? you mean you want to search through data ?

Comment: thats exactly the question I asked

Comment: well, on last question did you achieve setting your data to recyclerview ?